# execute stored procedure with timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to execute a stored procedure with a timeout value in SSMS?

Like:

```
EXEC dbo.StoredProcedureName timeoutValue(not parameter)
```

Comment: Topic also discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091783/is-it-possible-to-set-a-timeout-for-an-sql-query-on-microsoft-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't do this that way.
Insted you can configure the generic timeout of the server:

REF: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189040.aspx

You also can set this on SSMS:

REF [Changing the CommandTimeout in SQL Management studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137190/changing-the-commandtimeout-in-sql-management-studio)

Comment: Ok thanks. This is not an option for me but at least I know it's not possible then :)