# SSRS 2008 R2 Query Timeout Works Intermittently

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS report with the query timeout set to 30 seconds:

```
<Timeout>30</Timeout>
```

We have it set up to run from an ASPX page.  When I run it with parameters that cause the query to take more than 30 seconds it times out after running for slightly more than 30,000 ms of TimeDataRetrieval (as expected) with a status of rsProcessingAborted.

There was a case earlier this week that a user ran the same report from the same ASPX page with a TimeDataRetrieval of 286,393 (thats 4.8 minutes).

I want this query to always fail at 30 seconds of query time.  Any help would be appreciated.

Someone implied that this is a duplicate of [Is it possible to set a timeout for an SQL query on Microsoft SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091783/is-it-possible-to-set-a-timeout-for-an-sql-query-on-microsoft-sql-server) -- it is *not* because I have some instances where the query aborts as requested and some where it does not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set a timeout for an SQL query on Microsoft SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091783/is-it-possible-to-set-a-timeout-for-an-sql-query-on-microsoft-sql-server)

Comment: nope--not duplicate